# How to keep the display awake in a PhoneRTC video call?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonertc

I have a video chat in Android and iOS implemented with PhoneRTC, but after a few seconds of "inactivity", the display dims itself even though the video chat is still active.

How can I keep the display awake as long as the video chat is active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [org.chromium.power](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/tree/master/chrome-cordova/plugins/chrome.power) plugin. To install it, run:

```
cordova plugin install org.chromium.power
```

When the video chat starts, use the [requestKeepAwake API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/power#method-requestKeepAwake):

```
chrome.power.requestKeepAwake('display');
```

When the video chat ends, use the [releaseKeepAwake API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/power#method-releaseKeepAwake):

```
chrome.power.releaseKeepAwake();
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the power api in my own app, but when I add the code into my JS file, i get an undefined error. How exactly do I use the power api, e.g. where do I put the code, and what code exactly?